# PHP preg_split get rid of trailing spaces in just one line?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-split

How can i get rid of trailing spaces in `preg_split` result **without** using `preg_replace` to first remove all spaces from `$test` string?

```
$test   = 'One , Two,   Thee   ';
$test   = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $test);
$pieces = preg_split("/[,]/", $test);
```

Comment: You could use `trim` instead. Does it count?

Comment: @zerkms can't get the point of your comment. `trim` returns the string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end, not inside the string.

Comment: and you said nothing about "inside the string", you said "How can i get rid of trailing spaces"

Comment: @zerkms Yep, you right, sorry. Looking at `$test` make it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it must be `preg_split()` (you actually required that in the question) then this might help:

```
$test   = 'One , Two,   Thee   ';
$pieces = preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", trim($test), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

`trim()` is used to remove space before the first and behind the last element. (which `preg_split()` doesn't do - it removes only spaces around the commas)

Comment: +1 for `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`. I'll investigate further of `-1` parameter, thanks.

Comment: @Polmonino third parameter is the limit, -1 actually means "get all elements, no limit". This is the default value, but you must specify it explicitly when you want to use the fourth parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
$test = 'One , Two,   Thee   ';
$pieces = array_map('trim', explode(',', $test));
print_r($pieces);
```

Comment: Will explode handle the case of sep like ` ,    ` (with any number of spaces before or after)? I don't think so..

Comment: @Polmonino no it will not, this is why Frosty uses `array_map('trim', ..)`. trim() actually removes the whitespace before and after the text in each element.

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, great one there by @Kaii, meanwhile, based on a tip from his solution, I modified my code from :

```
function splitStringToArray($str){
    return preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
}
```

To :

```
function splitStringToArray($str){
    return preg_split('/\s+/', trim($str));
}
```

And now am getting the exact results I want, NO tailing space(s) in words process function. Hope this also helps someone. Cheers.